# How is it possible to edit Text in a flutter application?

Tags: flutter

I want to show a paragraph and once the user selects a part of it, somehow he can get the option to edit the selected text and the string will change and replace the old text, please tell me if that's possible.

I have found flutter_selectext plugin but it doesn't show in the examples if it's possible to edit the text or the string that provides the text to the widget it just shows that it can copy which I cannot use.

Comment: Edit the text in what way ? can you show an Image of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Selecting then editing the text any way possible I just want to change the string or the text in the widget that is used for that purpose.

Comment: check this github repository this may help you
https://github.com/zmqgithub/login_screen_ui_921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to have a functionality of EditText just like in android. I have a similar problem before. Here is how Solve it. Define the TextEditingController in State.
and you can initialize in the InitState. you can use listener for more controll of text ( like saving the previous old text)

```
class _ProfileEditPageState extends State<ProfileEditPage> {

  TextEditingController nameController;
  .. }


 @override
 void initState() {
 nameController = TextEditingController();
 super.initState();
 }
```

Here is how you can implement in your widget.

```
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  controller: nameController
                    ..text = _userProfileData.background, //this is your text
                ),
              ),
```